# Wave Function Probability calculation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, differentiation, probability

Redited

> The wave function of the particle at a certain instant is given as $$\psi(x)=Ae^{(-\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ikx)}.$$
>
> If $P1$ and $P2$ denote the probabilities of finding the
> particle in the range $a$ to $a + da$ and $2a$ to $2a + da$ respectively the ratio $\frac{P1}{P2}$ is

> a)$e^2$
> b)$e^3$
> c)$e^6 $
> d)$e^8$

This was the actual question and in this i made some changes for my understanding of the range a to $a+da$ and asking for different ranges.

Comment: a is a constant, what do you mean by da?

Comment: Yes a is a constant but it has nothing to do with integral. the integral will be carried wrt dx only. It is like limits are usually 0 to a or o to a/2.  Is there something wrong or i am have misunderstood you as the question which i have asked is correct?

Comment: If this is a question that someone asked you to solve, it might help if you actually phrased the question as you received it. It looks like you've paraphrased it here, and I suspect that something has been lost in that process. However, if the question does indeed read as you have described, then it is -- in my opinion -- a bad question.

Comment: Ok i will reedit my question @Philip

Comment: So it would appear that the question is indeed badly posed. The person who set it _probably_ meant to say $[a, a + \text{d} x]$ and $[2a, 2a + \text{d} x]$ respectively, but didn't think it mattered. What they obviously meant was "in an interval infinitesimally close to $a$" and "in an interval infinitesimally close to $2a$" respectively. You can use the method in my answer to answer this now.

Comment: @NeelamSharma Also, please don't make such drastic edits to your question. Someone reading this for the first time will not understand it unless they read the edit history. I would suggest that you spend a little time modifying the original question to make it more readable, including the actual question you were given, and the conceptual problem that you're facing, since otherwise you question risks getting closed very quickly as it stands right now.

Comment: @Philip thank you for being linnet and helping me out. I will note all these points for future. Just one thing normally we do integration to find the probability but here we did nothing as such why that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not completely clear to me what you're asking, so I might not be addressing your issue.

As to your conceptual question, this just boils down to the definition of a [Probability Density Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). If you have a probability density function called $\rho(x)$, then one can think of the quantity $\rho(x)\text{d}x$ as being the probability that $x$ lies within the infinitesimal interval $[x, x + \text{d} x ]$. Thus, given the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule):

$$\text{Probability that a result of an $x$ measurement will return a value in } [x + \text{d}x] = |\psi(x)|^2\,\text{d}x.$$

One way to convince yourself of this is to remember that the probability that the result $x$ occurs between two values $p$ and $q$ is:

$$\text{Probability that $x\in[p,q]$} = \int_{p}^q |\psi(x)|^2\,\text{d}x. \tag{1}\label{1}$$ Now, set $q = p+\text{d}x$, some infinitesimal amount. In this case, the entire integral just collapses into one term, since any function you're integrating is assumed (by definition) to be constant over the infinitesimal range $\text{d} x$. As a result,

$$\text{Probability that $x\in[p,q]$} = \int_{p}^{p+\text{d}x} |\psi(x)|^2\,\text{d}x = |\psi(p)|^2 \text{d}x. $$

Notice how if $\text{d}x = 0$, then the probability is 0. This is related to the fact that for continuous probability distributions, point probabilities are zero, since for such distributions [probabilities are measured over intervals, not single points](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda361.htm).

Therefore, to address your more specific question about the range $[a + \text{d}a]$, I'm afraid I'm at a bit of a loss: the value $a$ in this case is a  constant, and so the infinitesimal $\text{d}a = `0'$ and so looking for something in the range $[a + \text{d}a]$ doesn't seem to make any sense. The most sense I can make of this question is that you are interested in is:

$$\text{Probability that $(x=a)$} \text{ which is }= 0,$$

by the argument I gave above.

On the other hand, if the question is to find the probability that an $x$ measurement returns some value between $a$ and $a + b$, where $b$ is some number and not an infinitesimal, then of course all you have to do is use Equation (\ref{1}),

$$\text{Probability that $x\in[a ,a + b]$} = \int_{a}^{a+ b} |\psi(x)|^2\,\text{d}x,$$ which you can calculate (at least numerically) in this case.

Comment: as you stated in your answer in the comment, can you kindly reedit your answer with the solution (at that part which you explained) o that I can compare it and understand it as i am a bit confused by Muntafa has answered and yours.

Answer (score 0):

The probability to find the particle between $x$ and $x+dx$ is  $|{Ae^{(-\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ikx)}}|^2dx$. In this case the interval is $dx$, and it is infinitely small. If you want to find the probability in a finite interval, such as between $5a$ and $7a+da$, you need to calculate $\int_{5a}^{7a+da}{|Ae^{(-\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ikx)}|^2dx}$. If $da$ is infinitesimal, you can drop it from the integral limit because it too small compared with $7a$. (But, as I said in my comment, $a$ is a constant, thus $da$ has no meaning)